# Total of mathematical expression in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I written a part of a  my code to calculate the total of mathematical expression.(This not a full code it is a part of my code)

```
tot=10
temp=''
b=['+20', '-5', '*4', '/50']
for i in range(0,len(b)):
  temp=str(tot)+b[i]
  tot+=int(eval(temp))
print(tot)
```

In above code i am printing the total of expression

explanation:

```
10+20 ->30
30-5 -> 25
25*4 -> 100
100/50 -> 2
```

Output i got:

```
 382
```

Output i need:

```
2
```

Is my code is incorrect what changes i need to do??

Comment: `tot+=` should be `tot=`.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the evaluation in every iteration to total so the output you get is the sum of all answers. Rather, change the value of `tot` in every iteration.
Code:

```
tot=10
temp=''
b=['+20', '-5', '*4', '/50']
for i in range(0,len(b)):
  temp=str(tot)+b[i]
  tot=int(eval(temp))
print(tot)
```

Comment: thank you sir sorry for wasting your time thank you so much

Comment: @Hymdal, you didn't waste anyone's time, asking questions is not wasting time :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun (and assuming you have Python 3.10) you can avoid *eval()* (which is generally frowned upon anyway) with this:

```
total = 10
b = ['+20', '-5', '*4', '/50']

for e in b:
    v = int(e[1:])
    match e[0]:
        case '+':
            total += v
        case '-':
            total -= v
        case '*':
            total *= v
        case '/':
            total /= v
        case _:
            pass
print(total)
```

**Output:**

```
2.0
```

This also avoids the string manipulation seen in your original question and in some answers